# How do you implement a pattern over a bent plate in Autodesk Inventor?

Tags: cad, software, autodesk-inventor

I am attaching the model part as an Image below for your reference:-
[image: bent plate model so far]

I need the pattern like this on the above model.
[image: desired embossed pattern]

I have the model shown above, and want to put embossed lines 0.2 mm thick with 0.2 mm spacing in between on the top, sides, and the bends. The feature should be parallel to the horizontal section. I tried using emboss but I don't know how to emboss all three sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this, is simply to add the "embossed lines" *before* the bend.

Have a look at the modelling process below:

1. Extrude a flat plate. Because this model will be symmetrical this is only half the size of the final object.
2. Extrude a 'master rib'. This is 0.1mm away from the YZ plane, so that there's an 0.2mm gap once it's mirrored
3. Pattern the rib to cover the full plate (using the 'rectangular pattern' tool, with one direction defined
4. Bend the plate, using the 'Bend Part' tool. You will need to make a sketch on the surface of the plate, and draw a line at the point where you want the bend to start. The line defines the "end of the flat top", so if you want the overall width to be 20mm, with an internal bend radius of 2mm, and a plate thickness of 5mm, you would need the line 13mm from the YZ plane.
   N.B. You may have to click the word "Modify" on the ribbon to reveal this command if you have it hidden, or just use the "Search Help & Commands" window at the top right
5. Use the Extrude Tool with Cut Boolean to make the 'angled cutoff', as required
6. Finally mirror the part around the YZ plane to complete your component.

[image: Modelling with embossed lines]

Comment: Say u need to do it on a solid cube how to go about it?

Comment: Do it like this, and fill in the cube afterwards? Patterning along a curve is easy in SolidWorks, but tricky in Inventor, I’m afraid...